# How to check if a string includes any value of an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, include

My string is

```
str = "my string is this one"
```

and my array is

```
arr = ["no", "nothing", "only", "is"]
```

So, my string includes the **is** in the value of my array, I want to get the result `true`

How can I do this?

I want to use `include?` met

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check when the whole word is included case sensitive:

```
(str.split & arr).any?
#⇒ true
```

Case insensitive:

```
[str.split, arr].map { |a| a.map(&:downcase) }.reduce(&:&).any?
#⇒ true
```

To check if it includes any of `arr` anyhow:

```
arr.any?(&str.method(:include?))
#⇒ true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(str.downcase.split & arr.map(&:downcase)).any?
   #=> false
```

If it is known that all letters are of the same case.

```
(str.split & arr).any?
   #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a Regular expression. The good news is that it is generated for you - no syntax to learn. Other good news: it traverses the string only once.

```
re = Regexp.union(arr)  #your own regular expression without screws or bolts
p re.match?(str)  # => true
```

Comment: I believe you need word boundaries. For example, `str = "not"; arr = ["no"]` should not match. (Easy fix, nice approach.)